# What is the difference between monitoring and metering

Tags: grafana, monitoring, metering

I have a question.

I want to know the differences between monitoring and metering In the developer's world.

I think watching system logs, CPU usage, memory, and some other things using Grafana is Monitoring.

But I can't catch the exact meaning and usage of metering.
What is metering? and what is the difference between monitoring?

Answer (score 0):

Monitoring is generally used to check for functionality in the overall system. For example, it checks if sufficient memory exists, if there is a data drift, if requests exceed a certain threshold, etc. Metering collects metrics from targets and metrics are numerical. For example, levels of resource utilization, such as data storage volume, or HTTP request latency. Metering provides data for monitoring.